# CreateFontIndirect and control panel zoom factor

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I fill out a `LOGFONT` structure and use `CreateFontIndirect()` to create a font and draw a piece of text with it.  This is on Windows 7, so let's not discuss high dynamic DPI awareness or whatever its called on Windows 10.

With the control panel set to 100% default zoom factor, the text I draw looks however it looks.  What should happen if I change the control panel zoom factor to 125% or 150%?  I had expected that the text drawn, after a repaint/relogin/reboot, would look slightly larger, without me having to do anything programmically.  But it doesn't. Regardless of the zoom factor size, the text remains exactly the same.  What am I doing wrong?

My font height is hardcoded to `-7`.

The same applies to button sizes, I guess.  If I am figuring out button sizes programmically on the fly, and the buttons look ok at 100%, am I supposed to do additional calculations when displaying them at 125%? They look exactly the same unchanged size.

Comment: Don't describe your code. Show a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoding a negative value gives you:

> The font mapper transforms this value into device units and matches
>   its absolute value against the character height of the available
>   fonts.

If you look at the documentation for `CreateFont` you will find this formula

```
nHeight = -MulDiv(PointSize, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
```

and LOGPIXELSY basically gets the DPI and one inch contains 72 points. This is the formula you should use if you want a specific font point size.

This is the classic way of doing things and has been around forever. The point size was usually 8 before Vista but you should get it from the system/theme API. It is also [documented here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/74299/info-calculating-the-logical-height-and-point-size-of-a-font) in a support article with some more details. You can also get the `LOGFONT`s used by the system by asking for the [NONCLIENTMETRICS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729175(v=vs.85).aspx).

[This blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/10/24/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-for-desktop-applications-and-mixed-mode-dpi-scaling-in-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/) contains information about what Microsoft had to do to fix Notepad to be per-monitor DPI aware.

UI elements in a dialog should be based on dialog units. Dialog units vary based on the font but can be translated to pixels with [`MapDialogRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645502(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: yes, I have seen the formula and documentation -- and the resulting text that comes out when using it, looks abysmal.  I didnt think its working as expected.

Comment: You can find some pre-Win10 DPI documentation @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx You can use scale factor the way they do it there or simply just use a larger value if you actually want a larger font. If abysmal means blurry then you have not marked yourself as DPI aware.